# Generating plots by using twiddle (inline anonymous functions)

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to write a pipeline to create an age histogram for each Department based on the `attrition` data. I want to use the *inline anonymous functions* by **twiddle** using `map()`.

I tried the following but stuck at how exactly to generate histograms out of it.

```
attrition %>%
  nest(data = Department) %>%
  mutate(gg = map(data, ~ .x + theme(text = element_text(color = 'blue')))) %>%
  pull(gg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mtcars` as an example :

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -cyl)  %>%
  mutate(gg = map(data, ~ ggplot(.x) + aes(mpg) + geom_histogram())) %>%
  pull(gg)
```

This would give you list of plots.